# Microsoft SQL Server (2008 and 2008 R2) is not supported on this version of Windows

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, windows-server-2012-r2

In a sharepoint wfe server i saw below error many times why i get this error and how to solve this .
sharepoint wfe server O/S: windows server 2012 R2

```
database : sql server 2012 

Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-ApplicationExperienceInfrastructure
Date:          9/22/2015 11:10:30 AM
Event ID:      1
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      
User:          NETWORK SERVICE
Computer:      Xxx.xxxportal.com
Description:
The application (Microsoft SQL Server (2008 and 2008 R2), from vendor Microsoft) has the following problem: Microsoft SQL Server (2008 and 2008 R2) is not supported on this version of Windows. For more information, contact Microsoft.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-ApplicationExperienceInfrastructure"    <EventID>1</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>2</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-09-22T08:10:30.441883600Z" />
    <EventRecordID>62612</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="1272" ThreadID="1276" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Xxx.xxxportal.com</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-20" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="DBType">15</Data>
    <Data Name="AppNameCount">40</Data>
    <Data Name="AppName">Microsoft SQL Server (2008 and 2008 R2)</Data>
    <Data Name="VendorNameCount">10</Data>
    <Data Name="VendorName">Microsoft</Data>
    <Data Name="SummaryCount">126</Data>
    <Data Name="Summary">Microsoft SQL Server (2008 and 2008 R2) is not supported on this version of Windows. For more information, contact Microsoft.</Data>
    <Data Name="SessionID">0</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: check this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2846823

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you SQL server version should be that min level.

**For SQL Server 2008 R2**
You must apply SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2 or a later update. For more information, see How to obtain the latest service pack for SQL Server 2008 R2.

**For SQL Server 2008**
You must apply SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 3 or a later update.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2681562

Another thing, you can try to run the [SQL Server 2008 R2 BPA Information](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2022909) to check it.

Anything install on the WFE other than sharePoint? any sql or dirsync etc?

Comment: in this sharepoint  2013 farm all servers os version windows server 2012 r2 and sql server db version is sqlserver 2012 enterprise,

Comment: In wfe servers there are asp.net applications deployed and connectiong to sql server same as sharepoint farm